# Can't encrypt the string in OpenPGP.js

Tags: javascript, openpgp, openpgp.js

I am trying encrypt text with OpenPGP.js.

Here is an example of error: https://jsfiddle.net/7e2s516d/

```
let publicKeyArmored = `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=pnHg
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
`;

let messageEncrypt = openpgp.encrypt({
    message: openpgp.createMessage({ text: 'test' }),
  publicKeys: openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKeyArmored })
});

console.log(messageEncrypt);
```

I am using the latest version (5.0.0-3) of OpenPGP.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't check documentation of those functions.

1. `encrypt`, `createMessage` and `readKey` are returning a `Promise`, not a simple value (i.e. `Message` or `PublicKey`). Therefore you need to use those promises correctly.
2. `EncryptOptions` object that you pass to `encrypt` method should not have `publicKeys` property, but `encryptionKeys`

Once you do those changes it'll work fine.